# What word fits in this situation

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idioms, expression-choice

When someone applied for something and reasons for the application are not enough or not subject to even consideration, how do you say in English instead of unacceptable?  Does this sentence make sense? : The reasons do not come under the rule.  I have been searching what idiom fits in this situation for last 2 hours, but never found. Help me out please.

Answer (score 1):

So essentially you're talking about when somebody applies for something, lets say a job and their skills/attributes **don't:**

**match the specification**.

**fit the criterion**

**reach certain demands**

thus they are:

**unfit for the position**

**ineligible**

**unsuited**

In regards to a business situation/job application, the employer would write:

**unfortunately your application was unsuccessful at this time**

*I have received many of these :(*

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. These expressions are what I have been finding. How could I learn these expressions like native speakers always use in business situation.

Comment: Absolutely, check my latest edit @japanese

Comment: I will keep peeping your posts :P Best teacher ever!